# different IP addresses

Tags: network

I'm new in the Network world so I'm still trying to figure things out. I have a server with an IP address like 192.168.1 etc. There is other devices that communicate and share information with the server, all of them are DHCP enabled and the IP address is also something like 192.169.1.etc. but sometimes they reset after power failure  and change the IP to 169.254...... so i lost communication from the server with this devices. why this happen and how can i fix it?

Comment: Your question is not about information security as defined by [this article](http://security.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), and as such it is off-topic here.

Comment: Have a look at the DHCP settings of the device that your machines get their IP addresses from. But yes, this question is better suited to a networking specific board.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you have enabled Dynamic Host Configuration Protocol. Every time the host goes up, it tries to obtain a new IP and sometimes they are different from the last. Please follow below steps to set IPV4 to static

1. open control panel.
2. open network and sharing center.
3. right click on local area connection and select properties.
4. Select IPV4.
5. After selecting IPV4 choose properties.
6. select use the following IP address.
7. give your IP address which you want to connect.
8. check validate settings on exit.
9. click OK.

Now you have configured your PC with Static IP. After power failure and log back in the IP address will not change.